# Send object from background script to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to sent a object from my background.js to contentscript.js. The functions that do this are these:

```
// contentscript.js

chrome.extension.sendMessage({ message: 'getdata' }, function(response) {
    console.log(response.data); // Object {}
    console.log(response.data.property); // ERROR (see below)
});
```

-

```
// background.js
var data = { property: 'test' };

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === 'getdata') {
            sendResponse({ data: data });
        }
    }
);
```

-

```
The error: 
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://neneohfdjobjkpbdmapenhmpmofmnmpo/scripts/contentscript.js:99:70
    at messageListener (extensions::messaging:343:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:397:22)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:93:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:379:35)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:403:17)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:93:26)
```

I hope someone can help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed together the deprecated `chrome.extension.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage`. This leads to all kinds of fun stuff.

Solution: forget that `chrome.extension.sendMessage`/`chrome.extension.sendRequest` and corresponding events exist.

Switch to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

Comment: Hmmm, that is a good catch. But it did not solve my problem. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: Then I recommend you to double-check for typos in variables and string constants. Also, run a debugger on your background script to ensure data is being sent.